# Custom Toast Message - GridView

Tags: android

Image must appears with a custom toast message that states the first name of the picture person

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Integer[] PersonalPhoto = {R.drawable.user1, R.drawable.user2, 
 R.drawable.user3, R.drawable.user4, R.drawable.user5, R.drawable.user6, 
 R.drawable.user7, R.drawable.user8 };

ImageView pic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView grid = ( GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    final ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLarge);
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
   position, long id ) {



            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext( ), "Selected User " + (position), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pic.setImageResource(PersonalPhoto[position]);





        }
    });

}
```

The GridView have to display eight images. When a user select an image, first name will appear on the toast message

Answer (score 0):

seems no problem, just add `final` keyword.

```
final Integer[] PersonalPhoto = {R.drawable.user1, R.drawable.user2, 
 R.drawable.user3, R.drawable.user4, R.drawable.user5, R.drawable.user6, 
 R.drawable.user7, R.drawable.user8 };

final ImageView pic;
```